# I need a single column column chart for Google Charts

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I need a one column column-chart that has a vertical axis from 0 to 150000 and a bar that fills it (they have met their deductible completely). I thought I had what I read to do this as below, but that gives me a vertical axis of 0 to 400,000 and a bar up to 150,000.

Alternatively, I could use suggestions on how to display a single field whereas one can pay in full or in 4 payments to meet that deductible.

PLEASE help!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(barDisassembly);

    function barDisassembly() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Categories', 'Disassembly Fee'],
            ['N-1701', 150000]
        ]);

        var options = {
            chart: {
                width: 200,
                height: 400,
                legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 },
                vAxis: {
                    viewWindowMode:'explicit',
                    viewWindow:{
                        max:150000,
                        min:0
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        var bar = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('bar_disassembly'));

        bar.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `chart` from the options.
The only [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#configuration-options) associated with `chart` are `subtitle` and `title`...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(barDisassembly);

function barDisassembly() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Categories', 'Disassembly Fee'],
    ['N-1701', 150000]
  ]);

  var options = {
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    legend: {
      position: 'top',
      maxLines: 3
    },
    vAxis: {
      viewWindow: {
        max: 150000,
        min: 0
      }
    }
  };

  var bar = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('bar_disassembly'));

  bar.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="bar_disassembly"></div>
```

Comment: could you please clarify the second part of the question?